# Convert a ty to an ident in a macro_rules

Tags: rust, ident, macro-rules

I have a `macro_rules` that takes a `function_name` and calls `function_name_x()`. Right now I do that by passing `function_name` as an `ident`, and creating the new function name via `concat_idents!`.

The problem with this approach is that my IDE does not lint the `function_name` part because it takes is as an `ident`. I'd like to change that to a `ty` but I can't use it in `concat_idents!` if I do that.

Is there a solution?

```rust
macro_rules! decl_func {
    ($env:expr, $func:ident) => {{
        let f = concat_idents!($func, _to_ocaml);
        let binding = f($env, None);
        println!("{}", binding);
    }};
}
```

Comment: *"my IDE does not lint the `function_name` part"* - can you clarify the desired behavior? Its not clear to me what linting you're talking about.

Comment: `concat_idents` is nightly only. Might want to look into [the paste crate](https://lib.rs/crates/paste)

Comment: I should remark that if you want an identifier, you shouldn't use `ty` since it'll accept things like paths `some::nested::Struct` and templates `Vec::<i32>`

Comment: @kmdreko I want it to tell me if the function/type I wrote doesn't exist, and I want to be able to click to go to the definition (VSCode)

Comment: @kmdreko I realize that `ty` is probably not suited for a function name. Perhaps `tt` would be better? Right now my IDE doesn't seem to recognize that I'm passing a function name there.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your usage, I would say `ident` is the correct choice. While other things like, `path`, `tt`, `expr` may be appropriate for accepting a function in general, since you're only using it to create another identifier, `ident` makes the most sense.

---

By way of sophisticated monte-carlo analysis, the way rust-analyzer seems to handle syntax detection in macros by expanding it first, assessing what code is generated, and then back-referencing that info to the original macro parameters.

In the following example, the `decl_func1` call correctly links the `function_name` identifier to the function definition, while `decl_func2` call does not.

```
fn function_name() {}

macro_rules! decl_func1 {
    ($func:ident) => {
        $func();
    };
}

macro_rules! decl_func2 {
    ($func:ident) => {};
}

fn main() {
    decl_func1!(function_name);
    decl_func2!(function_name);
}
```

So in your code, rust-analyzer won't make the connection to `function_name` because the generated code only has `function_name_x`.

---

A potential workaround would be to introduce a statement into the macro that would syntactically use the identifier as is, but in a way where it ultimately does nothing. This may be a good idea anyway so that the compiler, not just rust-analyzer, can verify the identifier is what it should be. A couple ideas:

```
// would check that it is some kind of value
let _ = &$func;
```

```
// would check that it is a function with a signature that can take these types
let _ = || $func(1, 2);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! BTW I'm doing this because I have another attribute macro that generates a `func_to_ocaml()` function from a `#[my_macro]func()`. It feels a bit hacky, if it was a type I could generate an implementation on it and it would be cleaner...